# Yahoo login with R and rvest

Tags: r, forms, yahoo, rvest

I am trying to login to Yahoo using R to access my fantasy league. I am following Cory's code at [Yahoo login using rvest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36269476/yahoo-login-using-rvest) but without success.
When I try to submit the form I get the following error:

> Error: Unknown submission name 'signin'. Possible values: passwd

when I check the variable myform I noticed the following:

```
     <button submit> 'signin
```

There is no closing tilde for the submit button name. Could it be the cause that the submission button is not recognized?

Also, I am still using the username/password instead of username/phone check method.

Can I make just one submission? I noticed that whenever I press the "next" button on the login form the first and the second pages are the same, yahoo simply hides the username field.

Here is the code  @Dave2e

```
 library(rvest)
 username <- "xxxx"
 passwd <- "xxxxxx"
 league_id <-"yyyyyyy"

 uastring <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
 url <- "http://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/f1/"
 url <- paste0(url, league_id,"/players")
 s <- rvest::html_session(url, httr::user_agent(uastring))  
 myform <- rvest::html_form(s)[[1]]
 myform <- rvest::set_values(myform, username=username)
 # s <- suppressWarnings(rvest::submit_form(s, myform, submit="signin"))
 s <- rvest::submit_form(s, myform, submit="signin")
```

The commented line was in @cory 's original code.

Comment: Why don't you try using selenium driver to manipulate click actions?

Comment: If you post the code you are trying, it would be helpful as opposed to referring back to the previous post.

Comment: Answering to @amrrs, I do not know selenium and I am trying to teach myself R. I just picked my fantasy football league as an item of insterest to help me learn.

Answer (score 2):

I've had to change the code since then. I guess yahoo changed the submit button or whatever... Here's what works for me now, with one caveat, sometimes, I have to run it twice. I don't know why, but sometimes the first time I run it, I hit an error, but on the second time, it works.

Also, I've put it in a [package on github](https://github.com/corynissen/yahooFantasySports). You can install it via `devtools::install_github("corynissen/yahooFantasySports")`. There's only two functions there... one to login and the other to download a list of football players for each position. I used it for my fantasy draft preparations.

```
login <- function(league_id, username){
  if(nchar(league_id)!=6){stop("league_id must be six characters")}
  if(!is.character(username)){stop("username must be a character string")}

  uastring <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
  url <- "http://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/f1/"
  url <- paste0(url, league_id)

  s <- rvest::html_session(url, httr::user_agent(uastring))  
  myform <- rvest::html_form(s)[[1]]
  myform <- rvest::set_values(myform, username=username)
  #s <- suppressWarnings(rvest::submit_form(s, myform, submit="signin"))
  s <- suppressWarnings(rvest::submit_form(s, myform))
  s <- rvest::jump_to(s, s$response$url)
  myform <- rvest::html_form(s)[[1]]
  if("code" %in% names(myform$fields)){
    code <- readline(prompt="In your Yahoo app, find and click on the Account Key icon.\nGet the 8 character code and\nenter it here: ")
  }else{
    print("Unable to login")
    return(NULL)
  }
  myform <- rvest::set_values(myform, code=code)  
  s <- suppressWarnings(rvest::submit_form(s, myform, submit="verify"))
  if(grepl("authorize\\/verify", s$url)){
    print("Wrong code entered, unable to login")
    return(NULL)
  }else{
    print("Login successful")
  }
  s <- rvest::jump_to(s, s$response$url)
  return(s)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm. 
I had to alter my account login to do it from the phone. Could never make the changes using user/pass work. Need to study more. Also I had to add a couple of touches to the get player data function. Just add the bye week header and change s_S to S_PS to make it pick the projections instead of last season results.